# Bevel Shape not 45°

Tags: bevel

weird bevel shape coming from blender this morning.

Instead of the 45° bevel feature with a single edge I get a 10° bevel? I have been playing around with the shape 0 and 1. And it makes no difference?

Thoughts
[image]

How do I get back to normal bevels?

Comment: have you applied the scale of your object in Object mode?

Comment: Let me have a look

Comment: I have. How do I set the new scale as zero? I see Ctrl-A...

Comment: scale should be 1 not 0. In object mode default shortcut is CONTROL+A > SCALE

Comment: Like moonboots said, apply scale by Ctrl + A > Scale. Most probably that will solve it.

Comment: If the scale is not the issue, go into the settings of the bevel (the tab that appears in the bottom left of the viewport right after you do the bevel) and see if it's set to proportional (or "percentage"?).  If it is, set to offset or width.

Comment: Thank you @moonboots. Appreciate the help